# Linux crontab redirection log

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the cron set up as such, but the log file just has a number 50 written to it. Within the script I have another logfile in /tmp folder and that shows the echo outputs. Why is it missing here in the redirection log ?

```
/u02/dba/admin/controlm/jobs/cleanup_mountpoint.sh "/u03/archivelog" 95 4 "dbf.gz" "/u03/archivelog/DWP/KEEP/"> /u02/dba/admin/controlm/logs/cleanup_mountpoint.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you asking why when you are redirecting output in the script to one log file and the redirection on the script itself isn't seeing those same messages?

Comment: Hi @Etan Reisner yes. The logfiles in the script and outside dont match.

Comment: If you redirect the messages *in* the script (like `echo some message > testlog`) then they don't get to the redirection outside the script because you've *already* redirected them away from the script's standard output to the log file.

Comment: Try `(echo foo; echo bar > inner-file; echo blah) > outer-file` for a simple example of the idea (then remove `> inner-file` and run it again and see the difference). If you want the output going to file(s) and standard output that's what `tee` is for.

Comment: @EtanReisner , so then can i use the same log file name and destination in and out the file? Should I replace the > with the >> for redirecti0n then ?

Comment: You can use the same name inside and outside though your ordering of contents may (potentially) suffer because of it and yes, you would need `>>` inside the script at least.

Answer (score 0):

If the job is working then some things to review try:

1. Put SPACE in front of '>' ( "/u03/archivelog/DWP/KEEP/" > )
2. Try 'appending' the output: ( "/u03/archivelog/DWP/KEEP/" >> )
3. Review script - is it referencing the log file - perhaps 'clobbering it' in some way?
4. check ownership/perms for desired log file - Does the user running the cron job have 'write' permission?
5. change the log folder to /tmp/some_folder - working now?
6. if cron 'logging' is enabled you may also have some 'system logs' to review; does the user running the cron job have 'write access'?